# NodeJS + Express + Socket.IO : CANNOT GET ERROR

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm programming chat app using socket.io .
Chatting works well but trying to get 'http://myurl/upload', it give me the error"cannot GET//uplad".
What is the problem. I'm sorry that my English is so bad.
but please help me.
Here's my code.

```
    const express = require('express');
    const { createServer } = require('http');
    const { Server } = require('socket.io');
    const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(express.static('public')); //it is to bring images. it works well.
    
    app.get('/upload',(req,res,next)=>{
      res.send('hello');
    }); //it doesn't work...
    
    
    
    const httpServer = createServer(app);
    const io = new Server(httpServer);
    
    io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
       ... //skip
    }
    
     httpServer.listen(3000,hostname);
     console.log("Running at 3000");
```

Comment: ''app.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{ 
 res.send('hello');
});'' --> it works. well

Comment: Would you be able to show the client side code where you are calling ```/upload```

Comment: now, my codes are working well. it was the proxy problem(apache to nodejs).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your code to work.

There is one typo: you must close the `io.on()` function call:

```js
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        //    ... //skip
    }) // <-- needs closing ')'
```

You do no need the `hostname` param and you should pass a function callback to .listen:

```js
    httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("Running at 3000");
    });
```

Finally, make sure you requesting http://localhost:3000/upload
If you request http://localhost:3000/ you will get

```
Cannot GET /
```

Because you only mounted the /upload endpoint in express (not the / endpoint)

Comment: now, my codes are working well. it was the proxy problem(apache to nodejs).

Comment: Glad you got it working!